# "make this a quiz" and create answer key using FormApp in google spreadsheet script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I wrote a google spreadsheet script that parses a spreadsheet and creates a form with the data.

Once the form is created, I can manually go to the form settings -> Quizzes and then "make this a quiz". Once I make it a quiz, I can manually assign points and a correct answer to each problem.

Does anyone know a way to script this when creating the form? Specifically, in my google spreadsheet, my script uses FormApp to create the form and add questions. When the script creates the form, I want to add the setting "make this a quiz", and when the script creates each questions, I want to set the answer key and assign point values. I am not sure this ability exist as I could not find it in the FormApp class.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any method to make the Form a quiz.  I'm quite sure that it's not available at this moment.  When I did a search on "quiz" there was nothing found in the documentation.

Comment: I'm guessing that your option in the form to 'make this a quiz' comes courtesy of an add on from a third party that you've installed? Do you know the name of it?

Comment: Sandy, thank you for your comment, I think you are correct, I can not find anything in the documentation either. Phollingdrake, it is not a add on. Look under the gear looking "settings" icon in the form. You can manually set it there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on Google script functions for features introduced in June 2016 Google forms update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998570/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-google-script-functions-for-features-introduce)

Answer (score 1):

On April 27, 2017, Google added many new Google Script methods for handling Forms. The announcement is on the G Suite Developers Blog: [Create Quizzes in Google Forms with Apps Scripts](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/create-quizzes-in-google-forms-with.html) Among the additions is the `isQuiz()` function, which allows you to set the form as a quiz. The documentation (although very brief) is at the [Google Developers site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#isQuiz()). The Developers Blog has a detailed explanation (with sample code) of how to create a quiz using Apps Script.