# Where can I find documentation on Google script functions for features introduced in June 2016 Google forms update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am looking for documentation on Google script functions related to the new features introduced in the Google forms update for June 2016:

Make this a quiz

Assign points to questions

Add explanations to answers

See a summary of your responses

Choose what people can see after they submit

Send results via email

Go here for more information about features: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287

None of the reference documents have been updated  at the Google Developers site since the Google forms changes were implemented:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, Apps Script doesn't yet support the new features recently launched in the UI. When they include new functionalities, they usually publish them in the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/) and [Apps Developer Blog](https://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com), you can follow them to keep yourself updated.

Comment: Thank you ocordova. I will keep checking-in at the websites you suggested. Any idea how long these things usually take?

Answer (score 0):

On April 27, 2017, Google added many new Google Script methods for handling Forms. The announcement is on the G Suite Developers Blog: [Create Quizzes in Google Forms with Apps Scripts](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/create-quizzes-in-google-forms-with.html). Most of the methods I was originally looking for (Make this a quiz, Assign points to questions, Add explanations to answers, See a summary of your responses, and Choose what people can see after they submit) are included in the update. The documentation is at [Google's Developers site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form). The Developers Blog has a detailed explanation (with sample code) of how to create a quiz using Apps Script.